# Returning boolean from angular mat dialog and wait for afterclosed to perform task

Tags: angular-material, angular6, angular8, angular9, angular10

I have a stuck scenario. Here are the details:

I have several components - Comp_A, Comp_B etc etc which needs to call a service to do some calculation like:

```
Comp(A): Service.getStatus().subscribe(
(isYesOrNo)=>{
//do some action according to Component
if(isYesOrNo) //do something
else // do something
}
```

Service:

```
function 1 : getStatus() : Observable<boolean>{
 httpService.getData().map((responseOfApi)=>{
if(!responseOfApi) return false
else return showDialogAndWaitForOk()
})
}
function 2: showDialogAndWaitForOk() {
dialog.open(header, msg).afterClosed().subscribe(()=>{return false})
}
```

Problem: showDialogAndWaitForOk is a subscription, even if it return it will return a subscription but getStatus needs to return boolean only.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3jqhhc
Hint: click on hit api button - ***case 3 is never updated - this is the issue -  I want to show dialog in case 3 and then update the case 3 text***.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.